# How to find offending driver on Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, drivers

After unsuccessfull installation/uninstallation of the VPN software on Vista x64, I now have some broken drivers that prevent me from booting up with disabled digital signature check for drivers - Windows gives me a blue screen on boot. I need to do it sometimes to connect old USB hardware that doesn't have signed drivers.

How to find and clear off offending driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What message do you get on the Blue Screen?  The file given as the source of the BSoD may be the offending driver.  Write the filename down and then Google it to find out what it is.

To ensure the Blue Screen stays up long enough for you to look at it do the following:

1. Open System by clicking the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Maintenance, and then clicking System.
2. Click Advanced System Settings.  If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
3. Click the Advanced tab, and then, under Startup and Recovery, click Settings.

   [image: Startup and Recovery dialog]
4. Make sure "Automatically Restart" is **not** selected and click OK

(Alternatively, you can let Windows reboot and then examine the memory dump but writing down the filename from the BSoD is easier to start with.)

Comment: Unfortunately blue screen is flashing for less than a second before computer reboots by itself.

Comment: Added instructions on how to stop auto reboot when you get the BSoD.

Answer (score 0):

If you can boot into Safe mode (F8 while booting), you can rollback your system to its state as before the bungled installation.

If that doesn't work, you can also try to boot into the Last Known Good Configuration.